# Pointer with float values, determine the output

Tags: c, pointers

What is the output of the following C program?

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void abc (float, float, float *); 

 void main() { 
 float y = 2.5; 

 abc (6.5, y, &y); 
 printf ("%f\n",y); 
 } 

 void abc (float x, float y, float *z) { 
 y = y - 1; 
 *z = *z + x; 

 }
```

a)  1.5
b)  2.5
c)  8.0
d)  9.0
e)  9.5

The answer is d) 9.0. Could someone please explain why this is? I thought it would be c) 8.0 since in the function I updated the value of y as per y=y-1 to become 1.5. Thank you!

Comment: Why did you think it would be c?

Comment: Could you explain why you expect `8.0`?

Comment: maaan, use a debugger...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath maybe tell him (or her) about GDB: http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/ or about putting print statement's everywhere.

Comment: The right answer is 9.0 (d). The line: *z = *z + x, (2.5 + 6.5)

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that the `y` in `main` and the `y` in `abc` have the same name, but they are different. The one in `abc` is just a copy.

First, notice that the first line of the function `abc` is useless, it modifies `y`, but never uses `y` after that. Since when you call a function, a copy of each argument is made, this doesn't modify the `y` in `main`. And now the `y` in `abc` isn't used at all, so we can remove it from the parameters.

So you could rewrite `abc` as such :

```
void abc (float x, float *z) { 
    *z = *z + x; 
}
```

And since there's not much point in such a simple one-line function, we can rewrite your program like this :

```
void main() { 
    float y = 2.5;
    y = y + 6.5; 
    printf ("%f\n",y); 
}
```

Now the result is pretty obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, the third argument is a pointer to `y` in `main()`. That `y` value is being printed later on.

inside `abc()`, `float y` is local variable. any changes made to its value is not reflected back in the caller parameter.

OTOH, as per the logic of pointers, `*z` retains the computed value inside `abc()` thereby reflecting back the value to `main()`.

In short, the computed value inside `abc()` is reflected back using the third argument `z`.

Calculation for `z` ==> 6.5 + 2.5 = 9.0

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Sourav. I guess in my question I should have specified: why wouldn't the y update to a value of 1.5 according to y=y-1 in the function?

Comment: @LivBowden `y` is updated, but that `y` is local to `abc()`. the `y` in `main()` does not get affected. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 abc (6.5, y, &y);
```

Please note that here the last parameter is call by reference and you are passing the address of the variable `y`.

Later in the function `abc()` you do

```
*z = *z + x
```

`*z = 2.5` which is called dereferencing the pointer and the value stored in the address the pointer is pointing to is 2.5 and `x=6.5` as you are passing it by value.So

```
*z = 2.5 + 6.5 = 9.0
```

Now in `main()` the value of `y=9.0` because the value stored in the address of the variable `y` was modified by the function call `abc()`

Answer (score 0):

When calling `abc (6.5, y, &y)` inside the function it will look like this:

```
void abc (x = 6.5, y = 2.5, *z = 2.5) { 
 y = 2.5 - 1; // y = 1.5 
 *z = 2.5 + 6.5; // *z = 9.0
 }
```

And `*z` inside the function is same as `y` outside the function, so `y = 9.0`.